# How to make transparent box for CSS only for the text (inline)?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a header text with trasnparent box. Here's what I've done so far:
[image]

The code for that one is:

```
    <div class="item active">
        <img src="img/gunung2.jpg" alt="Chania">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h1 style="font-size: 60px;">SOMETHIG TO SHOW IN THE CAPTION</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.carousel-inner .item .carousel-caption {
    position: absolute; ;
    left: 240px;
    right: 240px;
    top: 50px;
    bottom: 300px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.498039);
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
```

But that's not what I want. I want the box forms only for the text, like my illustration below:

[image]

Can you help me what CSS code to make that thing?
Thank you.

Comment: Put each line of code to different `<span style="border: 2px solid black;">`

Comment: is this what you need : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/wgExRe or http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/ggdjNm ?